# Object values type recognition using generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I need to detect the function's param type (it's using the described type) and build the same object type according to the described type (recognize provided fields and get value types using the described one).

Typing:

```
// the describe type
type StorageData = {
  prop1: boolean;
  prop2: number;
  prop3: string;
  prop4: "static" | "dynamic";
};

type ParamsToGet = Partial<StorageData>;

type Callback<T> = (data: T) => void;

type Get = <T extends ParamsToGet>(params: T, callback: Callback<T>) => void;

declare const get: Get;
```

Using:

```
get({ prop1: false, prop4: "static", prop2: 1}, (data) => { ... });

/*
Current typing:

data: {
    snowfallColor: string;  // ok
    snowfallZtop: true;     // wtf? should be boolean
    snowfallCount: number;  // ok
}
*/
```

**The problem is** that all property value types are detecting correctly, instead of bools, in this case, I'm getting `true` or `false` instead of `boolean`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible unless you pass the type: `get<StorageData>(...)`?

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, yeah, it's an option to use it with providing/describing working type, but I'm confused that it work's except for one type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the generic type extend `StorageData`, which allows typescript to get more specific, you could instead have it extend `keyof StorageData`, which gives you `Partial`-like functionality but lets you retain the original types:

```
type Get = <K extends keyof StorageData, T = Pick<StorageData, K>>(params: T, callback: Callback<T>) => void;
```

Comment: Great and confusing!